# Fragment Activity Crash

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

im working with a class that extends fragmentactivity but it crashes when i run it. The logcat gives me this error " Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.one.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.one-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.one-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]"
Can anyone help?

```
     package com.example.one;

     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.Activity;
       import android.view.Menu;

     import android.os.Bundle;

      import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you declare your activity in the AndroidManifest ?

Comment: yes, the activity is declared

Comment: it works when i only put extends Activity

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of android do not have support for Fragments.
Right click your project , Choose Android Tools > add Support Library. Run your app again and it should work.